# What does there mean in "I don't agree with you there"?

Tags: word-usage

What does there mean in "I don't agree with you there"?

And what's the difference between having there and not having there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means

> I don't agree with you ***on that particular point*** or ***on that particular matter***.

More context would be needed to understand exactly what ***there*** refers to.

If you only say

> I don't agree with you.

it can mean that *I do not agree with you on all aspects of the problem, not only on a particular one*.